# Requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages | Laravel4

Tags: symfony, laravel-4, composer-php

I am getting this error when I was trying to install [Menu](https://github.com/vespakoen/menu/issues/new) package to generate navigation bar for Laravel 4.
I was doing it by following the installation instruction given on its GitHub page.
As per the instruction I added the **"vespakoen/menu": "dev-master"** line to my composer.json file and gave an `composer update` on Windows PowerShell

```
PS d:\xxx\yyy> composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0
    - Installation request for vespakoen/menu dev-master -> satisfiable by vespakoen/menu[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA3
    - vespakoen/menu dev-master requires orchestra/testbench 2.1.* -> satisfiable by orchestra/testbench[2.1.x-dev, v2.1
.0].
    - orchestra/testbench 2.1.x-dev requires laravel/framework 4.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.1.x-dev, v4.1
.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - orchestra/testbench v2.1.0 requires laravel/framework 4.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0,
 v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.0.0-BETA2, 4.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.1, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.10, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.11, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.2, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.3, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.4, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.5, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.6, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.7, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.8, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.9, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BET
A2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
```

My Laravel framework installation is "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it requires laravel 4.1 in order to work, check your composer.json you need to specify "laravel/framework": "4.*"
This will allow updating of your laravel installation to 4.x versions. Please note that this is not preferred for a production site (in case you are applying this to a production site).